# What is the server side comment tag in scala templates in play framework?

Tags: templates, scala, comments, playframework

I need to  comment my code server side (not rendered to client) in scala templates in play framework. What is the format of this tag?

Comment: Hm, I can't find anything obvious in the source code where they make a special case for comments, but maybe I'm just missing it. Neither `@{ // Comment }` or `@{ /* Comment */ }` works, does it?

Comment: @{ // Comment } gives compile error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
@{ /* Comment */ }
```

But I was hoping something even better (requiring less typing) is out there.

Answer (score 25):

The documentation does not explicitly say, but as the template engine is inspired by ASP.net Razor, I would guess it uses the same syntax, which is

```
@* comment here *@
```

Note the end comment is done with a closing @ symbol.

Answer (score 3):

`@* comment *@`  works in play framework  version 2

Comment: you may want to edit your answer to give some more context to it. As it is, it is difficult to understand. What does `Form play v2` mean here ?

Answer (score 2):

These two are working for scala-0.9.1 (on play framework):

```
@{ /* comment */ }

@{ // comment
}
```

But these not:

```
@{ // comment }
@* comment *@
```

Still, there's a lot of typing :(