# Play 2.0 - how to make Play stop parsing the code in comments of a template?

Tags: playframework-2.0

If I have some erroneous code, commented in a `*scala.html` template file in Play, it gives errors on it during compilation. How to make Play understand that this is just a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Server side comments in Play](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) should be written as (I have used them many times without any compilation problems):

```
@* your comment here *@
```

But according to the following post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398059/what-is-the-server-side-comment-tag-in-scala-templates-in-play-framework) This can give compile errors in scala templates (for Play! 1.x!)

Perhaps, but i doubt it, the following could work for you:

```
@{ /* Comment */ }
```